# extract subfolder within zip from s3

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am writing a program in python using pyspark that reads the files within folder of local system. Now, I want to read these files from s3. For ease, the datasets are zipped in s3. So, the folder structure is

datasets.zip -> datasets(folder) -> files

Now, I want to read these files in python spark. I figure out the following code:

```
val AccessKey = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_ACCESS_KEY"
val SecretKey = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SECRET_KEY"
val EncodedSecretKey = SecretKey.replace("/", "%2F")
val AwsBucketName = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_S3_BUCKET"
val MountName = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_MOUNT_NAME"

dbutils.fs.mount(s"s3a://$AccessKey:$EncodedSecretKey@$AwsBucketName", s"/mnt/$MountName")
myRDD = sc.textFile("/mnt/%s/...path_to_your_file..." % MOUNT_NAME)
myRDD.count()
```

But, I think this doesnot read all the files within the folder. How should I do it?

Thank you

Comment: You need to add the context of `sc` is it an import or what? Also I am very dubious about anything that is trying to mount a zip file with any function called `textFile`.

Comment: so basically the files contains list of images files which in my code is read using sc.binaryFiles("path to folder") in local filesystem. But this is not possible in s3

Comment: You are accessing S3->Zipfile->Dataset->Files by trying to opne ZIpfile as __text__ - this will not end well.

Comment: so how could I extract zip file of s3 into the folder so that I could read the folder as sc.binaryFiles("folder")